# How to re-execute a Rust main function?

Tags: function, syntax, rust

I am looking to attempt to re-run my application from inside of the application itself.

When the program initially runs, it will `try` for a file. If the file does not exist, it executes a `login` module and create the file; if it does exist, it will go straight to the main `application` module.

This `try` function is inside of the initial `fn main ()` function.

How would I re-execute the application's `main` function to re-evaluate whether the file exists?

(Does something like `self::main()` exist?)

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not make a seperate function, then run *that* twice? Running `main` twice seems like poor style to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`main` is just a function. Call it like any other function:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

static NUMBER_OF_RUNS: AtomicUsize = AtomicUsize::new(3);

fn main() {
    if 0 == NUMBER_OF_RUNS.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::SeqCst) {
        eprintln!("Ending");
    } else {
        eprintln!("Not done yet");
        main();
    }
}
```

```
Not done yet
Not done yet
Not done yet
Ending
```

---

Now, I would suggest that you *not do this*. It's basically just *weird*. Instead, use a loop. I don't even see where you need a loop, all you need is basic conditional logic:

```
use std::{fs::File, io};

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("my_file")
        .or_else(|_| login())
        .expect("Unable to open file");

    println!("main logic");
}

fn login() -> io::Result<File> {
    File::create("my_file")
}
```